# Unable to run the project in android phone

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework

I am trying to debbug the project in my android phone. However when I use (ionic cordova run android) I am getting this error:

[ERROR] native-run was not found on your PATH. Please install it globally:
npm i -g native-run

I tried this as well. Still I am getting the same error message.

Here is my ionic info list:

[image]